# trouble with "posting" svg in xml using ajax on jsfiddle

Tags: ajax, svg, xmlhttprequest, jsfiddle

Here's the fiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/k2CAs/

(I want to test if and how ajax requests for svg are handled differently from inline svg.)

The console says there's an error. But I've read through the xml and svg headers carefully and I don't see a typo. Is this an issue with jsfiddle itself or am I doing something wrong? Is this just another case of jquery not playing well with svg? Help very appreciated...

UPDATE: D'oh! I fixed the typo, and reduced the number of svg elements for simplicity but the xml response logged in the console is `null`:

http://jsfiddle.net/k2CAs/4/

I've fiddled and fiddled with the various content and data settings. Is there some special way I need to set up the posted svg to deserialize correctly to xml? Is that not handled by jquery? (And yes, I've looked carefully at the jquery ajax docs.)

Answer (score 0):

You have `xml: "<?xml version="1.0" ...</svg>"`

This string is bounded by double quotes (the one after the :) but contains double quotes inside too so it's not doing what you think it is.

The solution is to use one quote type (single or double) for the data and another to contain it as a string. In this case the easiest solution is to replace the initial and final quotes so you would have:

`xml: '<?xml version="1.0" ...</svg>'`

Comment: Ach! A bit of late night stupidity on my part there. Unfortunately, even with the opening and closing double quotes replaced with single quotes, I'm still getting an "Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token ILLEGAL" error in the console for the same first line of the xml. Any thoughts? I've looked at examples of using ajax with xml on jsfiddle, and they all seem to use libraries, which feels like the problem. Jquery doesn't much like svg it seems. (It would be great to see a working example that didn't use a library.)

Comment: You could try removing the <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?> line

Comment: Yep, tried that (and about a dozen other things). Still getting a null response.